# Make ExtJS filter `int` type with `equal` comparison

Tags: php, extjs, filter

I'm using `ExtJS` in one old (and not mine) project and I have to debug it.
So i have this one code in search form:

```
var pm = Ext.getCmp('ddlFltrPM').getValue();
if(pm && pm > 0)    
filters.push({dataIndex: 'project_manager_id', type: 'string', value: pm});
```

This works, but in php code function convert this filter in sql query like this:
`AND project_manager_id LIKE %...%` (by default converting function), because it is `string` search filed.

But i need **exact** match.
So when i try something like this:

```
var pm = Ext.getCmp('ddlFltrPM').getValue();
if(pm && pm > 0)    
filters.push({dataIndex: 'project_manager_id', type: 'int', comparison:'eq', value: pm});
```

..filter dont appear in POST. I've tried many variations of `type` and `comparison`, but nothing works.

**So how can I change this filter field to `int` with `eq` comparison?**

Thanks for your suggestions.
Stanislav.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue. But there were hard time debugging ExtJS code step-by-step. So the code:

```
var pm = Ext.getCmp('ddlFltrPM').getValue();
if(pm && pm > 0)    
filters.push({dataIndex: 'project_manager_id', type: 'int', value: {"eq":pm}});
```

Comment: Nice solution. Did you know you can accept your own answer ;)?

Comment: @A1rPun did you know, that only 21 hours lately? ;)