# Filter Store by int field in EXTJS

Tags: extjs, odata

I have a model and a store that work great. I can get the records from the odata source just fine. My issue lies with not being about to filter the store correctly.

**Model**

```
Ext.define('CostClass', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'CostClassID',
    fields: [{ name: 'CostClassID', mapping: 'WBSCostClassID', type: 'int' },
          { name: 'Class', mapping: 'Class', type: 'string' },
          { name: 'WBSCostSetID', mapping: 'WBSCostSetID', type: 'int' },
          { name: 'CostClassID', mapping: 'WBSCostClassID', type: 'int' },
          { name: 'UseForCAC', type: 'boolean'}]
});
```

**Store**

```
var valueStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        //autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        model: 'CostClass',
        remoteFilter: true,
        sorters: { property: 'Class', direction: 'ASC' },
        proxy: {
            type: 'odata',
            url: siteUrl + "_vti_bin/PerformancePortalData.svc/WBSCostClasses",
            noCache: false,
            sortParam: undefined,
            limitParam: undefined,
            startParam: undefined,
            pageParam: undefined,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'd'
            }
        }
    });
```

**Filter Code**

```
valueStore.filter([{ property: 'WBSCostSetID', value: 2, exactMatch: true}]);
```

This generates an Odata call that looks like `_vti_bin/PerformancePortalData.svc/WBSCostClasses?$filter=WBSCostSetID eq '2'` but that URI gives the following error:

```
Operator 'eq' incompatible with operand types 'System.Int32' and 'System.String' at position 13.
```

Obviously, I need this call to look like `$filter=WBSCostSetID eq 2`, but ***how do I change the filter code to do that***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking in the [Sencha Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.util.Filter), I was still at a loss. However, another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509839/make-extjs-filter-int-type-with-equal-comparison) gave me a clue to the answer.

Apparently (even though *not* in the documentation), there is a `type` parameter so my filter code just needed to be changed to the following (note the added **type: 'int'**):

```
valueStore.filter([{ property: 'WBSCostSetID', value: 2, type: 'int', exactMatch: true}]);
```